# Store time zone independent time-only in NSDate object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am creating an app which includes a timetable feature, allowing the user to specify periods in a particular day (e.g. Period 1 goes from 9:00 to 10:00; Period 2 goes from 10:00 to 11:00 and so on). As the app is backed by Core Data it seems sensible to store the periods as Core Data managed objects with two `NSDate` attributes: `startTime` and `endTime`.

Assuming that the periods cannot span multiple days, the date in the `NSDate` objects is irrelevant - I am only interested in the time. While one approach is to simply use `NSDateComponents` to extract the time (and ignore the date) if I am doing a comparison of `NSDate` objects, or sorting based upon those objects, then if the dates are different that will affect the comparison or sort. I was thinking that one way around this problem is to manually the `startTime` and `endTime` attributes to have the same (arbitrarily) chosen date. Is this the best way around the issue?

Additionally, the times (i.e. `NSDate` objects) need to be time zone independent. If the user travels from say Australia to the USA then I don't want all the times to now show they have a class in the middle of the night! Compensating for time zone changes is not relevant in this app, so I would like the times to stay static regardless of time zone. I would appreciate advice on this aspect too.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Why not just keep time as seconds since midnight?  Using modulo arithmetic you can easily divide that into hours/minutes/seconds when needed for display purposes.

Comment: That's an interesting approach - something which I had not considered. Could you perhaps provide an example in an answer? I will need to do the occasionally conversion between `NSDate` object and the (I assume) `int` storing seconds, since the time is selected and modified using a `UIDatePicker`.

Comment: You don't need to use a UIDatePicker.  You can use a UIPickerView or a UIStepper instead.  But you can always use `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` to convert to/from NSDate, leaving the date set to Jan 1, 2001.  (Do remember that the system will think this is GMT time, so any formatting you do (and any UIDatePicker) will have to have a GMT timezone.)

Comment: Keep in mind that `NSDate` does not record time zone. It's basically an object wrapper for an `NSTimeInterval`, i.e. a floating point number representing time since the epoch. Time zones only come in when you convert to/from something you display to the user.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the "day date" I would recommend to not use NSDate at all, otherwise you will run into various issues. As said in the comments NSDate is not timezone aware, this means you will do a lot of unnecessary conversions to make sure that your app works in all timezones.

I would as well use the approach to save seconds since midnight, or have two fields for hours and minutes since midnight. That basically is local time, always.

To get this information from a UIDatePicker you have to convert the NSDate into NSDateComponents

```
- (IBAction)datePickerChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    NSDate *date = sender.date;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    calendar.timeZone = sender.timeZone;

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

    NSInteger hours = components.hour;
    NSInteger minutes = components.minute;
    NSLog(@"%02ld:%02ld", (long)hours, (long)minutes);

    NSInteger secondsSinceMidnight = hours * (60*60) + minutes * 60;
    // save to core data
}
```

When you want to show your time in the datePicker you have to go the opposite way, you have to create a NSDate (that, for timezone reasons happens to be today) from the saved components. e.g.:

```
// get from core data
NSInteger secondsSinceMidnight = 8 * (60*60) + 30 * 60;

NSInteger minutes = (secondsSinceMidnight / 60) % 60;
NSInteger hours = (secondsSinceMidnight / 3600);
NSLog(@"%02ld:%02ld", (long)hours, (long)minutes);

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = datePicker.timeZone;

// use today as day, to avoid timezone issues
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
components.hour = hours;
components.minute = minutes;

datePicker.date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```